# 'float' object is unsubscriptable

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools, netcdf

thats what I get:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is unsubscriptable
```

Thats what I did:

```
import numpy as N
import itertools

#I created two lists, containing large amounts of numbers, i.e. 3.465

lx = [3.625, 4.625, ...]
ly = [41.435, 42.435, ...] #The lists are not the same size!

xy = list(itertools.product(lx,ly)) #create a nice "table" of my lists

#that iterttools gives me something like
print xy 
[(3.625, 41.435), (3.625, 42.435), (... , ..), ... ]

print xy[0][0]
print xy[0][1] #that works just fine, I can access the varios values of the tuple in the list


#down here is where the error occurs
#I basically try to access certain points in "lon"/"lat" with values from xy through `b` and `v`with that iteration. lon/lat are read earlier in the script 

b = -1
v = 1

for l in xy:
    b += 1
    idx = N.where(lon==l[b][b])[0][0]
    idy = N.where(lat==l[b][v])[0][0]
```

`lan/lot` are read earlier in the script. I am working with a netCDF file and this is the latitude/longitude,read into lan/lot.
Its an array, build with numpy.

Where is the mistake? 
I tried to convert `b` and `v` with `int()` to integers, but that did not help.
The `N.where` is accessing through the value from `xy` a certain value on a grid with which I want to proceed. If you need more code or some plots, let me know please.

Comment: the problem is [0][0] after your where call

Comment: Where and what is `lon` and `lat`?

Comment: @user3012759 why is that a problem?

Comment: @Stophface sorry... got confused ignore my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you loop over xy, each value of `l` is a single element of your xy list, one of the tuples.  The value of `l` in the first iteration of the loop is `(3.625, 41.435)`, the second is `(3.625, 42.435)`, and so on.

When you do `l[b]`, you get `3.625`.  When you do `l[b][b]`, you try to get the first element of `3.625`, but that is a float, so it has no indexes.  That gives you an error.

To put it another way, in the first iteration of the loop, `l` is the same as `xy[0]`, so `l[0]` is the same as `xy[0][0]`.  In the second iteration, `l` is the same as `xy[1]`, so `l[0]` is the same as `xy[1][0]`.  In the third iteration, `l` is equivalent to `xy[2]`, and so on.  So in the first iteration, `l[0][0]` is the same as `xy[0][0][0]`, but there is  no such thing so you get an error.

To get the first and second values of the tuple, using the indexing approach you could just do:

```
x = l[0]
y = l[1]
```

Or, in your case:

```
for l in xy:
    idx = N.where(lon==l[0])[0][0]
    idy = N.where(lat==l[1])[0][0]
```

However, the simplest solution would be to use what is called "tuple unpacking":

```
for x, y in xy:
    idx = N.where(lon==x)[0][0]
    idy = N.where(lat==y)[0][0]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
for l in xy:
    x, y = l
    idx = N.where(lon==x)[0][0]
    idy = N.where(lat==y)[0][0]
```

which in turn is equivalent to:

```
for l in xy:
    x = l[0]
    y = l[1]
    idx = N.where(lon==x)[0][0]
    idy = N.where(lat==y)[0][0]
```

Comment: I understand and I dont. How would I access then `3.625` and `41.435` differently? With that one it works: `xy[0][0]` and 
`xy[0][1]` With `xy[1]` I only access `(3.625, 41.435)`

Comment: that's because `xy` != `l`. `xy` is a list of tuples whereas `l` is a tuple. try to access `l[0][0]` in the loop and it will break

Comment: I have expanded the answer to explain how to actually make it work.

Comment: Ah, now I got it! Thanks a lot for your efforts!